# PHP script to download text from site, convert and store it locally

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I store text from a site to a local file?

So basically the script needs to do the following:

1. go to this site (fake site)

   `http://website/webtv/secure?url=http://streamserver.net/channel/channel.m3u8**&TIMESTAMP**`

where `TIMESTAMP` can be a timestamp to make it unique.

the site will respond with:

```json
{
    "url":"http://streamserver.net/channel/channel.m3u8?st=8frnWMzvuN209i-JaQ1iXA\u0026e=1451001462",
    "alternateUrl":"",
    "Ip":"IPADRESS"
}
```

2. Grab the url and convert the text as follows:

`http://streamserver.net/channel/channel.m3u8?st=8frnWMzvuN209i-JaQ1iXA\u0026e=1451001462`

must be:

`http://streamserver.net/channel/channel.m3u8?st=8frnWMzvuN209i-JaQ1iXA&e=1451001462`

so `\u0026e` is replaced by `&`

and store this text in a local m3u8 file.

I am looking for a script either php or any other code is welcome which can perform this. Any help is appreciated.

I tried a small script just to show the contents but then I get the error:
`Failed to open stream: HTTP request Failed!`

It seems that php tries to open it as a stream instead of a website. It should see it as a site because only then the response is sent.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://website/webtv/secure?url=http://streamserver.net/channel/channel.m3u8&1';
$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place where you can get free code. Tell us what you have done or what you tried to do.

Comment: I tried a very basic php script to just view the contents but then i get "failed to open stream" it should not think it is a stream and open it as being a browser so a html respons is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a tutorial website, so I am not going to provide you more details. You can try the following code:

```
<?php 
$json_url = "http://linktoyour.site"; //change the url to your needs
$data = file_get_contents($json_url); //Get the content from url
$json = json_decode($data, true); //Decodes string to JSON Object
$data_to_save=$json["url"]; //Change url to whatever key you want value of
$file = 'm3u8.txt'; //Change File name to your desire
file_put_contents($file, $data_to_save); //Writes to File
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also tried with JSON_URL but then i get:

"failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!" I guess it tries to open the stream instead of reading the contents of the site and store it in a local file.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is issue with your PHP configuration.

It like as `allow_url_fopen` is denied.

See more http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @newman! allow_url_fopen set to Off was exactly my problem, now all works as it should.